# cant get the wordpress search bar on the right position

Tags: html, css, wordpress, position

Im trying to get my wordpress search bar on the left from the cart button.
but the problem is i'm not able to do this.
i don't get it to work there is already some custom css to make it sticky(position fixed) but now i need to get the search bar on the good position.
I tried to do it with margin but i cant get it to work since what i tried put the search bar in front of the logo.

https://ima.nl/skin/ thats the website link i hope you can help me with just the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this css to set right position

```
#header-cart-search {       
    position: relative;
}    
#header-cart-search .widget_search_mini {
        left: 410px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        min-width: 388px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
    }
```